# Had a verified SSL/TLS implementation in a 'safe language' would it still have been vulnerable be to the heartbleed attack?

Tags: haskell, ssl, coq, agda, idris

[Here the author makes the claim](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7571847):

> Formalizing the TLS specification and proving that an implementation is consistent with it only shows that the implementation is logically correct. However, it does NOT show that the implementation is secure. Your implementation can be vulnerable to side-channel attacks (particularly timing attacks) while still being logically correct.

My question is: **Had a verified SSL/TLS implementation in a 'safe language' (ie Haskell, Idris) or checked with a theorem prover (Coq,Agda) would it still have been vulnerable be to the heartbleed attack?**

Comment: An OpenSSL implementation in a "safe language" would supposedly *not* be vulnerable to Heartbleed, which is specifically a giant flaw (not even a side channel attack) only possible in a language with direct raw memory access. Actual side channel attacks like timing attacks are certainly possible in any implementation. I'm not quite sure what the question really is. If you understand what a timing attack is, I think it's more opportune to ask for a proof that something *isn't* prone to it.

Comment: Using a language like Haskell or Agda would prevent whole classes of vulnerabilities and bugs _like_ Heartbleed, but there is nothing to prevent a logically correct implementation from having other vulnerabilities.  There's nothing preventing the TLS specification from having vulnerabilities itself.  Someone just has to be smart (or lucky) enough to find a weak point if one exists, the problem is that it's very difficult to say whether or not one does exist.

Comment: Heartbleed is not a side channel attack.  A side channel attack is something like this:  an attacker connects and times how long it takes for the server to do operations during the SSL handshake.  The exact amount of time could reveal something about what exponent is used in the server's private key, since the number of machine instructions used to do the operations may be dependent on that exponent.

Comment: @WarrenDew That is a very specific (though common and important) kind of side channel attack, namely a timing attack. Other side channel attacks use other "side channels" such as [sounds](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~tromer/acoustic/), electromagnetic radiation, power consumption, supposedly erased data (cold boot attack), etc. -- the general definition of a side channel attack is anything which breaks the system without breaking the math or brute forcing, i.e. anything abusing on the physical implementation. Heartbleed falls under that definition, I would think.

Comment: @delnan I agree.  I was just giving one example.  In no case is heartbleed a side channel attack, though.

Comment: @WarrenDew I told you why I think Heartbleed *is* a side channel attack. I'd like to hear *your* reasons as well. Heartbreak circumvents the crypto by exploiting a flaw in the implementation, doesn't it? Are you perhaps using a different (more narrow) definition of side channel attack?

Comment: Obviously my definition is narrower than yours.  In general I don't count bugs in the implementation as a side channel attack; it's an implementation of something other than was specified.  Even more generally, though, heartbleed isn't a cryptographic attack at all:  it doesn't allow the attacker to break into encrypted communications, except as a side effect.  Rather, heartbleed is a serious bug exploit, and it's mostly happenstance that the exploit appeared in cryptographic code.  If it had been unencrypted TCP that was vulnerable, the vulnerability would still have been just as serious.

Comment: FYI, some people have tried to formalize some part of openSSL / CSS in Coq and found a new bug: http://ccsinjection.lepidum.co.jp/blog/2014-06-05/CCS-Injection-en/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Side channel attacks are for instance timing attacks, e.g. you can get information about the secrets by measuring timing differences when using different inputs. It is already hard to do this right in a low level language like C where you have lots of control about processor instructions, cache handling, compiler optimizations etc. It is much harder to do this correctly in higher level languages - and be still efficient enough to be usable in real-world applications.